# Не работает PathCombine

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

*P.S: VS - 2015*

Пытаюсь сложить 2 пути но не получается, постоянные ошибки при использование функции `PathCombine`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Shlwapi.h" // <Shlwapi.h>
```

Допустим у меня есть папка Temp

```
TCHAR myPath[MAX_PATH];
GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, myPath);
```

И я хочу дать название папки, которую нужно создать в папке Temp

```
const std::wstring fname = L"MyDirectory";
```

Дальше функция для создание папки:

```
BOOL DirectoryExists(LPCTSTR szPath)
{
    DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(szPath);

    return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}
void createDirectoryRecursively(std::wstring path)
{
    unsigned int pos = 0;
    do
    {
        pos = path.find_first_of(L"\\/", pos + 1);
        CreateDirectory(path.substr(0, pos).c_str(), NULL);
    } while (pos != std::string::npos);
}
```

Теперь функция по слиянию папки `"Temp"` и `"MyDirectory"`

```
std::wstring directory = PathCombine(NULL, myPath, fname.c_str()); // Слияние 2 пути
if (DirectoryExists(directory.c_str()) == FALSE) // Проверка
createDirectoryRecursively(directory); // Создание папки
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Попробовал изменить на PathCombine**W**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.P.S: `std::wstring directory = std::wstring(myPath) + fname;` Так работает, но проблема с PathCombine осталась, как её решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте включить в проект библиотеку `ShLwApi.Lib`

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib,"ShLwApi.Lib")` Так ?

Comment: Можно и так, можно в самом проекте указать. Как вам удобнее.

Comment: Включил библиотеку, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Компоновщик указывает на неразрешенный внешний символ - он не знает, откуда брать эту функцию. Она находится в указанной библиотеке; можете просто заглянуть внутрь и убедиться. Так что если ошибка все равно та же - то, значит, библиотека не подключилась. Почему и как - надо разбираться, что у вас на машине и как вы ее подключили, все ли верно...

Comment: Проблему решил через `TEXT` -  `std::wstring directory = PathCombine(NULL,myPath, TEXT("MyDirectory"));`